# Can't execute code using click trigger jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code which is used for tabs, it works well when clicking the tabs and loads the content using an AJAX function, this is how the links look in the HTML code:

```
<ul class="tabset">
 <li class="category-all">
  <a id="latest-news.all" href="http://www.website.com/#latest-news.all">All</a>
 </li>
 <li class="category-games">
  <a id="latest-news.games" href="http://www.website.com/#latest-news.games">Games</a>
 </li>
 <li class="category-other">
  <a id="latest-news.other" href="http://www.website.com/#latest-news.other">Other</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the jQuery, I'll just quote the handler:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('ul.tabset li a').on('click', function (e) {
```

When the page loads, I try to open an specific tab using the URL hash in this way:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
        $(window.location.hash).click();
    }
```

But it doesn't work, I already tried the .trigger('click') version and it also doesn't work.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure its not timing try

```
 setTimeout(function{
    $(hash).click():
},5000);


document.ready(function(){
     $(hash).click():
}
```

Ensure the has is the id of the anchor ex://

```
#firstdiv
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're just missing to prevent the default click handler to execute in your `.on('click')` callback:

```
e.preventDefault();
```